# Strength of Little's MCAR

Tags: missing-data

My Little MCAR is significant, but i use a dataset of N=10.000, so almost everything is significant. Is it possible to see if the Missings are really not random, or that its just becouse of the huge amount of respondents? is there a strength of the MCAR?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "a strength."

Comment: i mean is it significant becouse there is a very small difference with the expected value, but the n is so big its significant anyway, or is there a big difference with the epected value. how not random is it. like the R squared with regression, is there something like  that